# scrollTop always returns 0 in safari

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, safari

the code below works perfectly in chrome, but does not work in safari (desktop & mobile)

```
const messageBody = document.querySelector(`.chatContainer`);
messageBody.scrollTop = messageBody.scrollHeight;
```

messageBody is a div with overflow-y: scroll

Every time an item is added to the div, it scrolls to the bottom.
Any idea how to make it work in safari?

Comment: post also some html, even beeter a fiddle working sample

Answer (score 0):

I have found to problem, it was a problem in my react code.
Every time I added a new element to my array, all of my components were rerendered. This was because I was overwrittin the existing id I gave them. 
The code that worked in chrome did not work in safari, because safari executed the code before all of the components were rendered.

Answer (score -1):

```
ScrollPosition.prototype.restore = function () {
    if (this.readyFor === 'up') {
        this.node.scrollTop = this.node.scrollHeight -        
        this.previousScrollHeightMinusTop;
    }
}
this.previousScrollHeightMinusTop = this.node.scrollHeight-this.node.scrollTop;
```

reference-
http://kirbysayshi.com/2013/08/19/maintaining-scroll-position-knockoutjs-list.html